# Web related content segfaults

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, crash, 22.10, systemd-coredump

I have a laptop (Lenovo Lenovo IP 5 15ARE05) only running ubuntu 22.10. I installed ubuntu on it and restored a backup on it.

Since start web related content keeps crashing. Firefox, vscode, chrome, Brave etc. crashes regularly. No other content crashes. The segfaults are often sudden and happen without any warning. Sometimes a tab crashes, sometimes the computer dies completely. Usually the computer freezes and needs to be turned off. It is more likely to happen when reopening the laptop when it has been in standby but seems to be random. Non web related processes don't crash.

When a process freezes killing it via terminal doesn't work. I can run "kill PID" in terminal but the process doesn't disappear.

I have run memtest, hardware diagnostics, it works with a live USB and I have googled every error message I can find.

Examples in syslog:

```
May  7 09:58:56 name kernel: [  715.197846] brave[22435]: segfault at 2c06c6 ip 000055b9e6b61082 sp 00007ffed3c028d0 error 4 in brave[55b9e5f05000+ae8d000]
May  7 09:58:56 name kernel: [  715.197868] Code: 8b b5 58 fd ff ff 84 c0 0f 85 3a fe ff ff 31 db e9 45 fe ff ff cc cc cc 55 48 89 e5 41 56 53 48 39 fe 74 5d 48 89 d3 49 89 f6 <48> 63 76 2c 48 01 f6 48 23 35 e8 d9 bf 0a e8 db ff ff ff 49 8b 06
May  7 09:58:56 name brave-browser.desktop[7037]: [0507/095856.823068:ERROR:directory_reader_posix.cc(42)] opendir /home/name/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Crash Reports/attachments/312f076b-6fd7-40dd-be50-60a1bc5bfd6a: No such file or directory (2)
```

Firefox:

```
May  7 10:20:28 name kernel: [ 2007.105856] Isolated Web Co[47300]: segfault at 2d0e41e34f00 ip 00007fc688ad104c sp 00007fff30404c10 error 4 in libxul.so[7fc6848ee000+5bd6000]
May  7 10:20:28 name kernel: [ 2007.105871] Code: 04 83 4e 8d 24 f8 4e 8d 34 bb 46 8b 2c bb 45 85 ed 0f 84 89 02 00 00 44 89 e8 83 e0 fe 44 39 d8 0f 85 df 00 00 00 49 8b 3c 24 <48> 8b 07 48 89 c1 48 c1 e9 20 4c 39 c1 0f 85 c8 00 00 00 48 89 54
```

```
May  7 15:19:16 name firefox.desktop[102535]: message repeated 10 times: [ [Child 102535, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox-mu7WaD/firefox-113.0+build1/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57]
May  7 15:19:17 name gnome-shell[6122]: Launching DING process
May  7 15:19:17 name nautilus[112857]: Could not delete '.meta.isrunning': No such file or directory
May  7 15:19:18 name rtkit-daemon[3301]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
May  7 15:19:18 name rtkit-daemon[3301]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
May  7 15:19:18 name dbus-daemon[5932]: [session uid=1000 pid=5932] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.381' (uid=1000 pid=113584 comm="gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rasters" label="unconfined")
May  7 15:19:18 name dbus-daemon[5932]: [session uid=1000 pid=5932] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
May  7 15:19:18 name gnome-shell[6122]: DING: Detected async api for thumbnails
May  7 15:19:18 name gnome-shell[6122]: DING: GNOME nautilus 43.0
May  7 15:19:18 name wpa_supplicant[2723]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-60 noise=9999 txrate=78000
May  7 15:19:18 name firefox.desktop[103357]: [Child 103357, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox-mu7WaD/firefox-113.0+build1/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
May  7 15:19:18 name firefox.desktop[103357]: message repeated 4 times: [ [Child 103357, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox-mu7WaD/firefox-113.0+build1/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57]
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. 22.10 is no longer supported. You may want to upgrade to 23.04 or reinstall 22.04, which is an LTS. If the problem persists afterwards, update this question with the version you installed 

Comment: https://endoflife.software/operating-systems/linux/ubuntu

Comment: Upgraded and made no difference

Comment: I get it to on Ubuntu 23.10. Segfault in Isolated Web Container: `kernel: Isolated Web Co[4773]: segfault at 7f528e259c20 ip 00007f52af14fc6a sp 00007ffd41508110 error 4 in libxul.so[7f52aba0d000+7f0e000] likely on CPU 1 (core 0, socket 1)` the memory address ("7f528e259c20") varies each time it happens.